# Using cursor with table that has duplicate column names

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

Let's say that `table1` has the columns `a`,`b`,`c` and `table2` has the columns `b`,`c`,`d`.

After joining the two tables, how should one iterate through the 'joined tables' with a cursor and extract for example, the value of column b form `table1`. How can I differentiate the duplicate column names?

One way I found is to give aliases to the columns, but that would mean that I have to manually type all the other columns of a `select *` statement even if only one column would have a duplicate.

Is there something similar to

```
for c in (select * from table1 join table2 on (...)) loop
     dbms_output.put_line(c.table1.b);
     dbms_output.put_line(c.table2.b);
end loop;
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you even use a cursor while you can solve it over set base solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually type all columns. Just use describe `table1` and `table2` and copy paste the column names by adding commas at the end and a common suffix for tables. You may use any editors like notepad++ or editplus for such things. It isn't so laborious as it may seem.

Another way is to construct the join query using `column_names` from `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`. You could then use it to open a `CURSOR` dynamically in your program.

```
WITH tab1 AS
(
         SELECT   listagg('t1.' ||column_name
                           ||' as '
                           ||column_name
                           ||'_t1' ,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )  
                           col_names FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('TABLE1') ), 


            tab2 AS ( SELECT LISTAGG('t2.'||column_name||' AS '||column_name||'_t2',',') 
                                 within GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) col_names
         FROM     user_tab_columns
         WHERE    table_name IN ('TABLE2') )
SELECT     'SELECT  '
                      || a.col_names
                      || nvl2(a.col_names, nvl2(b.col_names,',',NULL),NULL)
                      || b.col_names||' FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id'
FROM       tab1 a
cross join tab2 b;
```